# Using the CurrentRegion property in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a simple VBA macro to copy the data in a range that corresponds to the block of cells around an active cell in Sheet1 and Paste it in Sheet2. (preferably in the same address as of in Sheet1).

The code I have written is:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Cello As Range

Sub CopyCurrentRegion2()
    Set Cello = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ActiveCell.Address)
    Cello.CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cello)
End Sub
```

Please correct this prog. It is giving run time error: 1004.

Comment: Please have a look at the image attached to see the code I have written.

Comment: Please add the code as text to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub CopyStuff()
    With ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
        .Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(.Address)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student 

Would you mind telling me what is it that I have done wrong in the prog I have written.

Comment: @GireeshKodali  You were using a range within a range.